# behat not recognising some gherkin rows

Tags: php, behat

I'm trying to run behat, I made an scenario Outline but some of the rows with params are skipped and some of the variables are taken incorrectly.

This is the gherkin Scenario Outline written on the .feature with the functions that have assigned:

```
Scenario Outline: CreatePostUseCase service # tests/integration/BlogApp/Feature/BlogApp.feature:7
    Given an <userid>                         # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::aUserId()
    And an <email>        // <- email row is skipped and no anEmail() function assigned
    And a <password>                          # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::aTitle()   // <- why is assigning aTitle() in password?
    When creating and saving a User object    # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::creatingAndSavingAUserObject()
    Given a <title>    // <- why is not assigning aTitle() here?
    And a <body>       // <- this one is also skipped
    When creating a Post object               # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::creatingAPostObject()
    Given a <publish> param                   # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::aPublish()
    And persist the Post   // <- this one is also skipped
    Then an event should be launched          # IntegrationTests\BlogApp\Context\BlogAppContext::anEventShouldBeLaunched()
```

And this is the context:

```
/**
 * @Given an :userid
 */
public function aUserId($userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;
}

/**
 * @And an :email
 */
public function anEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = new Email($email);
}

/**
 * @And a :password
 */
public function aPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = new Password($password);
}

/**
 * @When creating and saving a User object
 */
public function creatingAndSavingAUserObject()
{
    $this->user = new User($this->userId, $this->email, $this->password);
    $this->userRepository = new UserRepository();
    $this->userRepository->save($this->user);
}

/**
 * @Given a :title
 */
public function aTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

/**
 * @And a :body
 */
public function aBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}

/**
 * @When creating a Post object
 */
public function creatingAPostObject()
{
    $this->user = new Post($this->title, $this->body);
}

/**
 * @Given a :publish param
 */
public function aPublishParam($publish)
{
    $this->publish = $publish;
}

/**
 * @And persist the Post
 */
public function persistThePost()
{
    $this->postRepository = new PostRepository();
    $this->eventQueue = new EventQueue();
    $this->createPostUseCase = new CreatePostUseCase($this->postRepository, $this->userRepository, $this->eventQueue);
    $this->createPostUseCase->execute($this->user, $this->post, $this->publish);
}

/**
 * @Then an event should be launched
 */
public function anEventShouldBeLaunched()
{
    $lastEvent = $this->eventQueue->getLastEvent();
    $event = $lastEvent->getPost();
    PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertEquals($event->getTitle(), $this->event->getTitle());
}
```

And these are the examples from the .feature

```
Examples:
  | userid   | email               | password    | title           | body                                                                               | publish |
  | 1        | test@email.com      | abcd1234    | foo bar         | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet textae lungum is dolorem fistrum et duodenum pecatorum  | NULL    |
  | 2        | fake@email.com      | password123 | baz geek        | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet textae lungum is dolorem fistrum et duodenum            | true    |
```

Something is wrong with my code, but I can't see what's wrong with it or where it is wrong. Can somebody help me to know why is skipping some params please?

Comment: Could you share/check the step definitions? For Cucumber the steps  'Given an <userid>'  and 'And an <email>'  are the same (used with different param) and both steps should be linked to the same step definition.  The same for the steps 'And a <password>', 'Given a <title>'  and  'And a <body>' - the three steps should be liked to 1 step definition (it doesn't take into account the key word). Could you check if it's correctly linked to the step defs and if you are calling the correct methods depending on the param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes them distinct is the Gherkin syntax, In your case:

`@And a :password` is the same as `@Given a :title` and the same as `@And an :email` because `:password` and the others are just some labels, they are not part of the step.

What Behat sees as a step is: `a <parameter>`

Add other distinct words, e.g.: `@Given a title :title`, `@And a password :password`, `@And an email :email`

> Better, I recommend reading about best practices for BDD. Avoid using steps just to set a parameter, use the parameter to generate a set of values in an array or in any way you need them.

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by myself after a few days, but this is exactly why it was not working and the correct solution to my problem. You have my upvote. Thank you.